# Can I remplace processor MergeContent by another processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a processor that can replace MergeContent.
When I collect my files with ListSFTP-->FetchSFTP-->MergeContent , I use mergecontent to merge all files into one document. However I am asked to specify the minimum number of entries and the maximum number of entries but sometimes my files can be up to 1 million files or more.otherwise it merges the files into several small documents. I need to merge all the files into one document, so that the merge.count attribute gives me the total number of files received and merged.

Comment: How do you define when you have _all_ files?

Comment: Hi Sdairs, I merge all the files with mergecontent to implement a counter to calculate the number of lines and files number. If I can implement a counter to get the total number of lines of the files without merging them too it would be welcome.

Comment: Why do you need the number of lines in a list if files? How you are going to use it?

Comment: Hi daggett, can you write me on coulibalyjustin90@gmail.com. I can give you more details